# How can I add photos from src in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I put my image file like this in NetBeans
[image]

I tried to add an image in FinalRecreation like this

```
new JLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("..\\FinalRecreation\\VOSB_01.jpg"));
```

However, I know know why it won't work, the image would never come out.

Comment: Use something more like ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/FinalRecreation/VOSB_01.jpg")) to load the image, you'll need to wrap the result in a ImageIcon, but that should get you started

Comment: You should remove `..` by actual parent directory name; it'd probably solve your problem.

Comment: but if i used the actual directory, wouldn't the whole thing stop when i turn them into a .jar and give to someone else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the data as a resource. When you load as a resource, you engaged the classloader to search through the classpath for a file, so it can be included in a jar and distributed with the app.

Assuming your image file name is in a top level package called resources, the following code would work for loading BufferedImages, it would take a little bit of effort to adapt to read ImageIcon, but the code to open the InputStream to the resource should be the same.

*edit:* It looks like ImageIcon has a constructor that takes an Image, so you should be able to pass the BufferedImage into that [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.awt.Image%29).

```
String name = "resources/your_image.jpg";
try(BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
    YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name));) {
    if(input != null) {
        ImageIcon iicon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(input));
        // do something with iicon
    }
    else {
        // could not find resource - do something 
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // problem loading resource - do something
}
```